# jQuery Growl in PHP script not working

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to run Jquery growl notification plugin in my php file but it is not working. I just want to display this notification once in the start. Is ther any alternative in php ? Ref [GROWL](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/)

The code is given below

```
<?php


if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']))
{
  $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
  foreach ($cookies as $cookie)
  {
    $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
    $name = trim($parts[0]);
    setcookie($name, '', time() - 1000);
    setcookie($name, '', time() - 1000, '/');
  }
}

?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>UnSquaring the Wheel</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="css/images/unsquaringlogo_small.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styling.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script src="javascript/jquery.growl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="stylesheets/jquery.growl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
  echo '<script>
  $.growl({ title: "Growl", message: "The kitten is awake!" });</script>';
?>



  <!--login modal-->
  <div id="loginModal" class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <!--  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button> -->
          <div class="logo" >
            <img src=css/images/unsquaringlogo.png height="180" width="700">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="one no-color"></div><div class="two no-color"></div><div class="three no-color"></div><div class="four no-color"></div>
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 7%"></div>
          </div>
          Customer Experience<br>
          How "designed" are your customer facing activities?

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
    function checker()
{
   var checkedBox=0;
  //var chx = document.getElementsByName('ans1');
  var chx=document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i=0; i<chx.length; i++)
  {
    if ( chx[i].checked&&chx[i].type==='radio') {
        {

                checkedBox++;

        }

    } 
  }

  if (checkedBox!=1)
  {
      alert('select answer');
  return false;


  }
  else
  {
     return true;

  }


}

</script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The error i get is

```
GET http://localhost/unsq/javascript/jquery.growl.js 
v1ce.php:13 Uncaught TypeError: $.growl is not a function(anonymous function) @ v1ce.php:13
```

Comment: I think you didn't link the growl JS correctly. Please make sure to attach the JS plugins correctly then give a try and let me know if not working. Thanks.

Comment: Press F12 to show the debug bar in your browser and go to the console tab. Refresh your page by pressing F5 and you will discover that your script jquery.growl.js is not loaded due to a bas path or a tipo.

Comment: You need to download the Growl code, unzip/untar, create a javascript folder in your root folder and put the jquery.growl.js file in it.